# Searching for cms with in place editing of content in page templates

Tags: content-management-system

I have a brochure style website and I'm looking to add a lightweight cms to it. I'd like something that allows me to write page templates and define areas of those templates that can be quickly edited by a content admin. I would love to be able to have some sort of in-place editing or simple modal.

I'll also need to pull a list of blog posts from an existing wordpress blog. I realize that I might need to right this part custom or tack it on to the solution that I eventually settle on.

I've been looking at Unify CMS and I like what I see, but it won't work with any template system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.simplecms.com/

Comment: Very sweet, I've settled on expression engine though. I don't have time too look further into this right now but SimpleCMS wins for being the coolest looking.

Comment: As it happens I use EE most of the time, the site I'm working on right now is EE based. I'd classify it as mid-weight between something like SimpleCMS and Drupal (heavyweight framework).

Answer (score 0):

If you can write templates with HTML/CSS/PHP then all you need is OneFileCMS. I've used it before and it's EXTREMELY simple. It categorizes your pages and allows you to write to them from a small backend.

All the pages on your website would therefore have the content controlled by the cms and the visuals can be made with regular html/css methods.

http://onefilecms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ive started aptcms.com just for this situation. Its still in early stages but has potential. It uses a templating system similar to perch. To create a new editable "block" all you need to do is insert:

```
<?php block("blockName")?>
```

It also has the ability to have various page templates and a basic CMS.

To incude the CMS all you need to do is insert:

```
  <?php nav()?>

  <?php title()?>
  <?php content()?>
```

Have a look? [aptcms.com](http://aptcms.com)